# Plugin CP page causes white screen

Tags: plugin-development, error-message

I'll start off by saying my plugin is working perfectly locally. The problem is when I upload to my server. My plugin is for a contact form. It handles the submission, and logs the entry in the db.

I have a page in the CP for it as well - this is the page that is giving me the white screen.

With `devMode` I am seeing this in the logs:

```
[error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /path-to-my-site/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
```

So I looked up that file, and to me it seems that the system can't find a template?

I don't get any errors - although when I try to submit my form, I do get a 500 error. Could it be a permissions problem?

**EDIT**

Everything else in the entire site/app is working perfectly, so I know it's something with the plugin page.

My plugin "settings" page renders/works fine. It's when I click on the top "tab" to access my plugin's page within the CP that fails.

**EDIT 2**

I'm wondering if it's a case-sensitive thing now though. I don't see that exact error in the log file anymore.

I know with CodeIgniter, locally things work great, but when I upload to my server (CentOS) I get white screens. It's because of the case is all strange.

I have followed the suggested guidelines for plugin development:

```
controllers
    ContactFormPlugin.php
    controllers
        ContactFormController.php
            class ContactFormController extends BaseController {...}
    models
        ContactFormModel.php
            class ContactFormModel extends BaseModel{...}

   records
        ContactFormRecord.php
            class ContactFormRecord extends BaseRecord{...}
   
   resources
        ...

   services
         ContactFormService.php
             class ContactFormService extends BaseApplicationComponent {...}

   templates
       ...

   variables
       ContactFormVariable.php
           class ContactFormVariable {...}
```

...and so on.

My host is Rackspace, has anyone experienced this?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the 500 error?

Comment: It's an ajax submit, so it's just javascript trace through jQuery. I have updated my question...I think it might be something else?

Comment: Could be case sensitivity.  Can you share the class names as well?

Comment: Hrm... that looks O.K. to me.  Anything in your Apache error logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad, Thank you again for your help.

I found the problem, although I'm not sure of "why". In my service file, I have this line:

```
$email->body = craft()->templates->renderString($settings->welcomeEmailMessage, ['firstName' => $contact->firstName]);
```

After digging though log file(s), I found the error. "Unexpected '['"

It needed to be this:

```
$email->body = craft()->templates->renderString($settings->welcomeEmailMessage, array('firstName' => $contact->firstName));
```

Because everything was working perfectly on my local machine, (newer version of php) I wonder if that's the root cause.

Comment: Yup... the `[]` is PHP 5.4+ [short array syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Your production box probably has PHP 5.3, which doesn't recognize it.