# Installing the Charge plugin breaks plugin page

Tags: plugin-charge

I am attempting to install the [Charge plugin](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge) on a Craft site.  When I upload the plugin folder I get an error when opening the plugin page that says that the page cannot be loaded.  It works locally.  If I remove the plugin folder that page loads.  There is not a Craft error, I get an error that the page is "unable to handle the request", or just a total white screen. Anyone aware of an issue with the plugin?  I could not find anything here or online about it.

The folder is in the correct place and all the files are there, nothing has been tampered with or altered that would cause an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer at the bottom of the page [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/plugin-cp-page-causes-white-screen) ended up solving my issue.

The plugin was using php short array syntax " [ ] " which is available in 5.4 + and the server was set at 5.3.29.  When I changed that it worked perfectly.